# Split a numeric value into single digit spans

Tags: javascript, split, numbers, number-formatting

I have following code which counts down hours to a certain time. For the CSS purpose I need the digits to be split into single spans for example:

```
<p>Hours Left</p>
<span>4</span>
<span>6</span>
```

and not `<span>46</span>`

Could you help me achieve it?

I'm using the following code:

```js
var end = new Date('12/18/2018');

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
  var now = new Date();
  var distance = end - now;
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
    return;
  }
  var hours = Math.floor((distance) / _hour);
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours;
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
var hours = 12;
var hours_html = hours.toString().replace(/(.)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
// "<span>1</span><span>2</span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the hour value and join it back together:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tjb13adp/)**

Details:

Setting these lines:

```
var split_hours = (hours+"").split('');

document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =  '<span>'+split_hours.join('</span><span>')+'</span>';
```

It's not the cleanest solution possible but works stable.

Comment: @Palf [this is how you say thank you on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I did upvote you but since I don't have enough rep. it is hidden